# Can I update session via Ajax and after PHP read this session?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, refresh

In my "estabelecimento.php" I send data via Ajax to "carrinho.php" and this was stored in a session.
I need to access the session that was created on the "carrinho.php" when I refresh the browser.

estabelecimento.php

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['prato'])){
        echo'have session';
    } else {
        echo'session not found';
    }
?>
<script>
$.ajax({
        url: "carrinho.php",
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            idPrato     : idPrato,
            quantidade  : quantidade,
            detalhes    : detalhes,
            acao        : acao
        }
    });
</script>
```

carrinho.php

```
<?php

    session_start();

    // add items to session
    if ($_REQUEST['acao'] == 'cadastrar'){
        if (empty($_SESSION['prato'])){
            $_SESSION['prato'][] = $_REQUEST['idPrato'];
        } else {
            if(!in_array($_REQUEST['idPrato'],$_SESSION['prato'])){
                $_SESSION['prato'][] .= $_REQUEST['idPrato'];
            }
        }
    }

    // remove item from session
    if ($_REQUEST['acao'] == 'remover'){
        $removePrato = array_search($_REQUEST['idPrato'], $_SESSION['prato']);
        unset($_SESSION['prato'][$removePrato]);
    }
?>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION` is specific to a user session, not to a particular instance of a particular php script. `$_SESSION` exists solely to allow data to be shared between pages in a user session.

Answer (score 0):

Add `session_start();` after the opening `<?php` tag in `estabelecimento.php`.

Answer (score 0):

to get session data on estabelecimento.php page you should start session

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['prato'])){
        echo'have session';
    } else {
        echo'session not found';
    }
?>
```

`session_start` — Start new or resume existing session

Comment: In the full code I already had started the session but have one session in the "carrinho.php" file and other in "estabelecimento.php" file with the same name.

Output in "estabelecimento.php": Array ( [0] => )
Output in "carrinho.php": Array ( [0] => 43 [1] => 63 [2] => 67 )